# Tensorflow clip_by_value versus Keras NonNeg

Tags: tensorflow, keras, constraints

I want to constrain a Tensorflow [Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) to be non-negative via the constraint keyword argument. Should I use [clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value) from base tensorflow or [NonNeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/constraints/NonNeg) from Keras?  Here is my implementation of the clip_by_value constraint:

```
def make_nonneg(x):
    return clip_by_value(x,0.0,np.inf)
```

Also, do these both work equally well if I end up using the variable in code wrapped in a @tf.function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of taste and depends on the way you use it. If you define a model using Keras layers and want to put a constraint during training, it is very convenient to use Keras constraints:

```
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_constraint=NonNeg()))
```

But what it effectively does it pretty similar to `clip_by_value`:

```
  def __call__(self, w):
    return w * math_ops.cast(math_ops.greater_equal(w, 0.), K.floatx())
```

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/constraints.py#L93

So, the `NonNeg` constraint is just a callable object wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing I found curious is the keras constraint sometimes produced (-0.0) values wheras the clip_by_value constraint always had 0.0. I'm currently using the clip_by_value for this reason, because numerically the -0.0 might actually be negative. I suppose I could always add a small constant to prevent this.